# Non-normal data, manova and kruskal_test

Tags: r, manova, kruskal-wallis-test

I am trying to perform a statistical test on a large data frame. For this, I was thinking to find differences between groups using MANOVA.
I have 70 columns and 2 independent variables.

In the example hereafter I use only 3 columns, but the example is useful to keep the structure of my code:

```
test_df=data.frame(c1=runif(100, -1, 1), c2=runif(100, -1, 1),
                   c3=runif(100, -1, 1), prop1=sample(c("a","b","c"),100, replace=TRUE),
                       prop2=sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), 100, replace=TRUE))


manova( formula=as.formula(paste0("cbind(", paste(colnames(test_df[,1:3]), collapse=", " ), ") ~ prop1 + prop2")), data=test_df)
```

The formula in manova is:

```
"cbind(c1, c2, c3) ~ prop1 + prop2"
```

But since I have 70 columns in my real data, I had to find a way to print the variables in a short and concise way.

The problem is that the various columns are not normally distributed, therefore I cannot use MANOVA but rather Kruskal Wallis.
How should I proceed with kruskal_test (from the library rstatix)?
Or should I use kruskal.test?

If I do:

```
kruskal.test( formula=as.formula(paste0("cbind(", paste(colnames(test_df[,1:3]), collapse=", " ), ") ~ prop1 + prop2")), data=test_df)
```

I get:

```
Error in kruskal.test.formula(formula = as.formula(paste0("cbind(", paste(colnames(test_df[,  : 
  'formula' should be of the form response ~ group
```

Comment: Don't use cryptic code when describing a problem with only 3 columns.   Just write out the formula using regular notation.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question and make the formula more readable.  But having 70 columns I had to use that "paste" in the formula.